# Mean value for a concave function over $[0,1]$ VS $f(1/2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, convex-analysis

I am looking for a concave function $f(x)$ for which the integral over $[0,1]$ is bigger than $f(1/2)$.

That is, a function which mean value between 0 and 1 is bigger than the middle value of the function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) applied to $ 2\, f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-f(x)$, that is a convex function, that simply cannot happen. If you like to prove it in a direct way, consider that concavity implies midpoint-concavity, hence for any $h\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ we have:
$$ f\left(\frac{1}{2}+h\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}-h\right)\leq 2\,f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) $$
and by integrating the previous inequality over $h\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ we get:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx \leq f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$

Comment: @GabrielBalassa: You're welcome. Please consider to accept and/or upvote this answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a CONVEX function satisfying this (in fact any strictly convex function will do), but not a concave function. For any $x \in [0,1/2]$ you have that $f(1/2) \geq (f(1/2+x) + f(1/2 - x))/2$ if $f$ is concave. Thus when you integrate $\int_0^1 f$, you will get that $f(1/2)$ is greater than or equal to the integral.

Comment: How do you know that f(1/2) is greater or equal than f(1/2 +x) + f(1/2 -x) divided by 2?

Comment: @GabrielBalassa That is one of the definitions of a concave function, at least if your function is continuous. Other definitions of concavity imply that one.